# Resolution to getContentResolver().openInputStream(uri) for google drive file causes StorageFileLoadException[authentication_failure]

Tags: android

A strange error opening a Google Drive file from a chooser which only starting occurring recently on one of the 2 devices I'm testing on.

The error returned from openInputStream() is:

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: StorageFileLoadException[authentication_failure]
at android.database.DatabaseUtils.readExceptionWithFileNotFoundExceptionFromParcel(DatabaseUtils.java:144)
at android.content.ContentProviderProxy.openTypedAssetFile(ContentProviderNative.java:692)
at android.content.ContentResolver.openTypedAssetFileDescriptor(ContentResolver.java:1107)
at android.content.ContentResolver.openAssetFileDescriptor(ContentResolver.java:944)
at android.content.ContentResolver.openInputStream(ContentResolver.java:664)
at
```

...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just to help anyone else who sees this error, perhaps you'll also find the solution is to update all the Google apps on the device (possibly Google Drive app was the essential one).

Comment: Happens to me in 2023. Last version of Google Drive

Comment: Maybe it happens when we try to pick images too often and there is some kind of throttling in Google Drive, but I'm not sure.